# Bypass the alert and error that occur while screen scraping

Tags: javascript, screen-scraping

I have created a web page to screen scrape a site, while scraping from the other site; there is some error on that site so it's throwing an error (object expected). But finally I get my result perfectly.

It shows that the error occurs in my program. Is it possible to bypass those errors (without showing them on the screen). I don't want to show those errors and also is it possible to bypass the alert box without showing it on the screen while scraping.

Please guide me.

Comment: HOw come screenscraping another site throws error in your site? Are you trying to display the scrapped contents?

Comment: yes, using API i fetch the content of the screen, then parse the content and display the needed things in my site

Comment: hmmmm!!! copyright issues??? doesn't sound good :)

Comment: Curious why you chose to scrape in the browser and not do that from your server using php/curl ?

Answer (score 1):

You could try to redirect window.onerror:

```
var _oldonerror = window.onerror;
window.onerror = function(errorMsg,url,lineNr) { return true; };
```

Comment: please explain, what these lines will do? Will it throw the error

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how do you scrap the site, I don't know, but if yo're installing the content in javascript by eval or something like that, you can try *try-catch* block :

```
try
{
   // your content injected to page here.
}
catch(err)
{
   alert(err.description);
}
```

or you can clear script elements before including to your site with this regex :

```
(<script\b[^>]*>.*?</script>)
```